# Why can't I set the JAVA_HOME VARIABLE in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: java, variables, ubuntu, path, installation

I am having difficulties installing the JDK in Ubuntu, I can't manage to make it work. Could somebody let me know what I am doing wrong?

1- I Downloaded jdk-6u35-linux-i586.bin from oracle's web site

2- I moved the downloaded file to *home/*

3- I transformed it into an executable using *chmod +x jdk-6u35-linux-i586.bin*

4- I executed it using sudo ./jdk1.6.0_35

5- I moved the folder with the jdk to /usr/local using
*mv jdk1.6.0_35/ /usr/local/*

6- I opened the .bashrc with the "kate" editor and i added the following lines(This file was completely empty by the way)

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_35/
>
> export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

7- I typed java -version but didn't work. This is what the console displays

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install <one of the packages>` ?

Comment: Also, you can run it manually using: `source .bashrc`

Comment: Please show the output of `echo $PATH` and `ls -la /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_35/bin` and `/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/java -version`

Comment: `echo $PATH` returns this: `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
` and `ls -la /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_35/bin` displays many tools such as `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  47479 Aug 29 00:47 java`

Comment: what about `echo $JAVA_HOME` and `/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/java -version`?  Also, I notice that your JAVA_HOME ends with a slash, and then when creating your path you do $JAVA_HOME/bin, which would create /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_35//bin in your path.

Comment: @digitaljoel `echo $JAVA_HOME` Does not return anything and `/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/java -version` returns the Java version

Comment: @digitaljoel I removed the slash same thing occurs. 
It is correct the way I edit the file?, by using`sudo kate bashrc` after editing i close the terminal and open again but still don't work

Comment: @nos I tried opening it using kate .bashrc, but i cant save it, it says that i have no permisions. What kind of permisions do i need if I don't want to use sudo?
This is the content i want to put in that file: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_35
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: @nos Sorry,I don't understand, how do you mean I created it? Was that file there already or it got created when i executed the installation of the JDK in step 4? To perform step 4 I think i must use `sudo`.

Comment: @nos sorry i didn't know that kate would create that file, I thought it already existed. I will try to use vi .bashrc instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.bashrc` is run when you start Bash, so your changes to it won't take effect within the same session. Try opening a new window and running your command.

Comment: I closed and opened the terminal but same occurs. Don't know what could it be.

Answer (score 0):

Update your sudo command, and try with:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Type:

```
java -version
```

to check

If that fails, go in `Software centre`, you should find java JDK under `Developer tools` category.

Comment: I want to do it manually without using the apt-get command if possible

Comment: What do you mean manualy? This is much better, and easier way too.

Comment: I don't want to use apt-get I just want to install it manually and know why it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
update-java-alternatives 
usage: update-java-alternatives [--jre-headless] [--jre] [--plugin] [ -t|--test|-v|--verbose]
           -l|--list [<jname>]
           -s|--set <jname>
           -a|--auto
           -h|-?|--help
```

or

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/java" 2
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "java" "/usr/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/javaws" 2
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/javaws" 2
```

then switch

Answer (score 0):

I add in the end of .bashrc file

export JAVA_HOME="/home/apps/jdk1.7.0_13"
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

After you set JAVA_HOME variable, you must logout ubuntu and login against. It's worked for me